# Load remote site with options 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Tags: wordpress, iframe, same-origin-policy, x-frame-options

I'm running WordPress on NGINX at of the sites. But I found a Paradox.

When I'm trying to "iframe" remote URL the remote page ( the remote page have parametrs 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin') into EDIT WordPress mode - actualy the Page is loading ( I'm using Visual Composer plugin for page edeting).

But when I opening my WordPress page in "incognito mode" - the iFrame page is not loading and in Google Chrome Console show me 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin' issue.

Any have decision why page is loading in WordPress editing page mode? And not in usual mode (when user not loged in).

Thx